# liip_imagine generate wrong cache url with aws s3 (liip_imagine, vich_uploader, flysystem)

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, vichuploaderbundle, liipimaginebundle, flysystem

I currently have a problem for the configuration of liip_imagine.
My setup :

- Symfony 6.4
- vichuploader 2.3
- liipimagine 2.12
- league/flysystem
- aws/aws-sdk-php

I first installed vichuploader with flysystem, and it works, after that I trying to add liipimagine, but the url generated is not on my aws s3.

- website domain : *mywebsite.com*
- s3 domain : *asset.mywebsite.com*
- url generated from liipimagine : *mywebsite.com/media/cache/resolve/md/facility/photo/big-img-65d760d9afe9a372425826.jpg*

This parts working well, I can upload image and display it on my twig :

vich_uploader.yaml :

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    storage: flysystem 
    metadata:
            type: attribute
    mappings:   
        facility_photo:
            upload_destination: s3.facility_photo
            uri_prefix: '%asset_s3_url%/facility/photo'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\SmartUniqueNamer
            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

flysystem.yaml :

```
flysystem:
    storages:
        s3.facility_photo:
            adapter: 'aws'
            visibility: public
            options:
                client: 'Aws\S3\S3Client'
                bucket: '%amazon_s3_bucket%'
                prefix: 'facility/photo'
                streamReads: true
```

services.yaml :

```
services:
    Aws\S3\S3Client:
        arguments:
            -
                version: "%amazon_s3_version%"
                region: "%amazon_s3_region%"
                endpoint: "https://s3.%amazon_s3_region%.amazonaws.com"
                credentials:
                    key: "%amazon_s3_key%"
                    secret: "%amazon_s3_secret%"
```

But so I added liipimagine :

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        cache_resolver_aws_s3:
            aws_s3:
                client_config:
                    credentials:
                        key:    "%amazon_s3_key%"
                        secret: "%amazon_s3_secret%"
                    region: "%amazon_s3_region%"
                    version: "%amazon_s3_version%"
                bucket: "%amazon_s3_bucket%"
                get_options:
                    Scheme: https
                put_options:
                    CacheControl: "max-age=86400"

    loaders:
        loader_aws_s3:
            flysystem:
                filesystem_service: 's3.facility_photo'

    filter_sets :
        cache: ~

        md:
            data_loader: loader_aws_s3
            cache: cache_resolver_aws_s3
            quality: 100
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

I tried to add the filter 'md' in my twig :

`<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(photo, 'imageFile', 'App\\Entity\\PhotoFacility') | imagine_filter('md') }}" />`

He will not found the url from s3, but on my website domain :
mywebsite.com/media/cache/resolve/md/facility/photo/big-img-65d760d9afe9a372425826.jpg

Did I forget some configuration ?
I followed the [liipimage docs](https://symfony.com/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/current/index.html)

Help would be welcome, thanking you in advance for your collaboration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, it wasn't a liipimagine configuration issue, but a flysystem.

In league/flysystem package, league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/AwsS3V3Adapter.php, I I checked the `fetchFileMetadata()` function, the value of 'Key' generated in :

```
$arguments = ['Bucket' => $this->bucket, 'Key' => $this->prefixer->prefixPath($path)];
```

`facility/photo/facility/photo/big-img-65d760d9afe9a372425826.jpg` (duplicate prefix 'facility/photo')

So the `$result = $this->client->execute($command);` generate an error, because the request respond an error.

To fix it, I just had to remove the prefix from `flysystem.yaml` :

```
s3.facility_photo:
            adapter: 'aws'
            visibility: public
            options:
                client: 'Aws\S3\S3Client'
                bucket: '%amazon_s3_bucket%'
                # prefix: 'facility/photo'
                streamReads: true
```

Because 'facility/photo' was already generated by the `vich_uploader.yaml` :

```
facility_photo:
            upload_destination: s3.facility_photo
            uri_prefix: '%asset_s3_url%/facility/photo'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\SmartUniqueNamer
            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

After that, liipimagine had a functional response, so it generated the right link using my s3.

Feel free to edit my post to correct my English mistakes ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar setup except that I am using oneupFlysystemBundle instead, but I think this could help:

I think you need to change the resolver to something like

```
resolvers:
    flysystem_resolver:
        flysystem:
            filesystem_service: s3.facility_photo
            root_url:           '%uploads_base_url%'
            cache_prefix:       media/cache
cache: flysystem_resolver
```

and remove the `cache` key from your filter sets.

Also I have

```
uploads_base_url: '%env(AWS_BUCKET_BASE_URL)%'
```

defined in `services.yaml`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried but I still have the same problem.
Even if I change the value of  ```cache_prefix: ``` , the url generated is still mywebsite.com/media/cache.
Is it possible that my liip's configuration isn't load ?

Comment: I'm trying without using flyingSystem, but [AWS S3 Resolver](https://symfony.com/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/current/cache-resolver/aws_s3.html), but got the same problem.